# How to reference a component's data from its method in Vue with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I started a vue.js project with typescript and I want to use single file components, and not class-styled ones. 
I constantly get error TS2339 when trying to reference my components' data, with the "this" keyword:

```
export default { 
  data(){ 
    return { x: 10 as number };
  },
  methods: {
    foo() {
      if(this.x > 10) {
        return this.x;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It always leads to "TS2339 Property 'x' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is briefly explained in the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage).

You need to use the following syntax in a SFC

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
export default Vue.extend({
  
})
</script>
```